# Define initial parameters of a nonlinear fit with no information

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, least-squares

I was wondering if there exists a technical way to choose initial parameters to these kind of problems (as they can take virtually any form). My question arises from the fact that my solution depends a little on initial parameters (as usual). My fit consists of 10 parameters and approximately 5120 data points (x,y,z) and has non linear constraints. I have been doing this by brute force, that is, trying parameters randomly and trying to observe a pattern but it led me nowhere.

I also have tried using MATLAB's Genetic Algorithm (to find a global optimum) but with no success as it seems my function has a ton of local minima.

For the purpose of my problem, I need justfy in some manner the reasons behind choosing initial parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Without any insight on the model and likely values of the parameters, the search space is too large for anything feasible. Think that just trying ten values for every parameter corresponds to ten billion combinations.
There is no magical black box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Bayesian Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization) to find a global optimum for expensive black box functions. Matlab describes it's implementation [bayesopt][2] as

> Select optimal machine learning hyperparameters using Bayesian optimization

but you can use it to optimize any function. Bayesian Optimization works by updating a prior belief over a distribution of functions with the observed data.

To speed up the optimization I would recommend adding your existing data via the `InitialX` and `InitialObjective` input arguments.